# Recommended approach for complex Contact Us form in .html file hosted on a linux server?

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net, html, contactus

I am building a contact us form for the first time and based on what I've Googled what I'm looking to build isn't very common so my assumption is it is a bit more complex than the average form.

I don't know any PHP but there are hundreds of examples of contact us forms using it so it's not a problem to break one down.

I'm just trying to figure out what language to use? I've seen JavaScript based, I've seen PHP, I've also seen asp.net.

So I don't know what is the best way to go about doing it and If I should be concerned about security?

My website is in a .html file, and it is a one pager that will use modal windows if that makes a difference.

The form will contain the following fields:

```
`radio` Have a question
`radio` Request a quote (if this is selected show budget, services, and file attachment fields)

Full Name: (required)
Organization:
website:
Email: (required)
Select a service (required)
Budget: $ (enter amount, numbers commas and decimals only)
Attach file: (max 50mb)
"Enter a message" (required)
[] Send me a copy
[Submit]
[after submitting form changes to thank you msg] Thank you for contacting us, we will be in touch within two business days.
```

My domain is hosted on Godaddy and does have phpMyAdmin if that matters.

I appreciate any feedback I can get!

Thanks.

p.s I looked for a dedicated discussions section but doesn't appear to be one, so I apologise if this questions is too broad.

Comment: since your website host have phpmyadmin, that means it is best to use php. you can use your hosting email to send email via your contact us page thru php with curl support.

Comment: hi, thanks GeneCode. Should I be concerned about any security issues when implementing php? (like if I do it wrong for example)

Comment: A simple no-code solution is to use something like Google Forms which will give you the code.

Comment: oh interesting I didn't come across that in my search, thanks Arran!